# Pythontex: imported .py file sync

Tags: latexmk, import, pythontex

I've managed to make Pythontex working with Latexmk, the problem is that whenever I make changes to an included python file, it's old state persists in Latex unless I delete the auxiliary files and compile again. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
\inputpygments{python}{test.py}
\end{document}
```

with test.py having:

```
print(0)
```

The first run gives 0, as intended. But once I make changes to test.py, like making it:

```
print(1)
```

compiling the Latex document just keeps showing 0 unless I delete the generated files upon compiling it, mainly pythontex-files-test folder. There is another solution, right?

Comment: Hmmm... it appears that latexmk does detect the change in test.py and re-runs things; otherwise it would just say nothing has changed and refuse to do anything.

Comment: I find a more basic difficulty.  Instead of using latexmk, I just ran the commands manually.  First round: pdflatex, pythontex, pdflatex.  That gave the expected contents of the pdf file. Second round: change test.py, then run pdflatex, pythontex, pdflatex. The pdf file didn't show the contents of the changed test.py file.  Only by deleting the auxiliary files, and then running the commands could I get a correctly updated pdf file. So I think it's actually a pythontex problem, possibly a bug, and **probably** not a latexmk problem.